# Google Maps API V3 custom controls position

Tags: google-maps

I've read docs about positioning controls on the map(`TOP`, `TOP_LEFT`, etc), but Is there any way to make custom position? For example: `left: 20px; top: 200px`;
I just want to have in top_left corner my logo and zoom control right under logo. 
And how to remove pan control in navigation controls? I want to have only zoom control in default style(not minimized).
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Position Non Custom Control Google Maps (v3 API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924456/custom-position-non-custom-control-google-maps-v3-api)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although the question is rather old, with almost 3k views it still seems to draw interest - So, here is my solution:

#### Wrap the controls!

First we have to find the container-element, where Google puts the control. This depends on which controls we want to use on the map. Google doesn't use unique ids for those containers. But all the controls have the class "gmnoprint" in common. So just counting the elements with "gmnoprint" does the job. Say we only want to use the "ZoomControlStyle.SMALL"-control. It's always the last element with "gmnoprint".

Now, we can simply style the element - Right? No. As soon as you zoom or resize the map, Google resets the styling of the controls. Bad luck, but: We can wrap a container around the controls and style this container!

Using jQuery, this is a really simple task:

```js
$('div.gmnoprint').last().parent().wrap('<div id="newPos" />');
```

We only have to make sure, the control is fully loaded by the time we try to wrap it. It's not totally bulletproof I guess, but using the MapsEventListener "tilesloaded" does a pretty good job:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
    // We only want to wrap once!
    if($('#newPos').length==0){
        $('div.gmnoprint').last().parent().wrap('<div id="newPos" />');
    }
});
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/jfPZH/ (not working, see *Update Feb 2016*)

Of course if you don't like the initial flicker and want a more reliable version you can do all kinds of improvements like fadeIn etc: http://jsfiddle.net/vVLWg/ (not working, see *Update Feb 2016*)

*So, I hope some of you will find this useful - Have fun!*

Update: With this method you can position any other control (e.g. the controls of the [Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing)) as well. You just have to make sure to select the right container! This is a modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/jP65p/1/ (somehow still working)

**Update**: As of Feb 2016 Google seems to have changed the positioning of the map controls. This does not break my solution. It just needs some adjustment. So here are the updated fiddles:

Simple: http://jsfiddle.net/hbnrqqoz/
Fancy: http://jsfiddle.net/2Luk68w5/

Comment: It is a hack - because Google doesn't want us to position the controls anywhere else. There is no proper official solution. But my hack didn't fail yet...

Comment: I'm trying to use this technique for Drawing Tools using the Drawing library, but I'm not sure how it can be done. I tried forking the JSFiddle that was shared in this post. Have a look at mine here. http://jsfiddle.net/MekkT/

Comment: See edit and example: http://jsfiddle.net/jP65p/ Btw: You had a typo in your jsfiddle…

Comment: @AvL I should've checked my JSFiddle because I thought I had fixed the typo as I noticed it. In any case, thanks for your solution!

Comment: @AvL If we were to customize the 'look' of these buttons, can your same technique be used to achieve that? For example, I am trying to tweak the shadow on the Drawing Library buttons.

Comment: @kolor: Sure you can! Just use use `#newPos .gmnoprint > div` as a selector: http://jsfiddle.net/jP65p/1/

Comment: @AvL Simply awesome. I was trying `#newPost > div` and it didn't work. But now I see the flow. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: `$('div.gmnoprint:eq(-1), div.gmnoprint:eq(-3)');` worked for me for selecting panControl and zoomControl

Comment: @VinceLowe: Thanks for your hint. It does still work! See Update…

Answer (score 7):

It is extremely simple, just add this to your css file!

```
div.gmnoprint { padding-top: 50px; }
```

It will move the control 50px down with no hacks or anything!

Comment: Works only if you don't have other controls around. They'll overlap.

Comment: @givanse Is there a reason you can't also position your other controls?

Comment: You can, but you'll have to manually manage any overlaps, flow etc. (the UI responsiveness of your app). Map controls are meant to be positioned using [ControlPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls). Within your custom control you can increase white space by nesting divs and using margins or paddings.

Comment: This just _looks_ right but it doesn't _work_: http://jsfiddle.net/C5xzQ/ (Try to actually zoom the map by clicking on the zoom-buttons…)

Comment: Do **not** use CSS to customize your map. This is undocumented and subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom control for your logo, and add it to the map to position it. You can't set the location of the control directly beyond the constants, but you can offset the location using padding on your control div.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html

Comment: Really, this is the only reliable way to handle this ATM.

Comment: For a fully-worked example of this, see https://github.com/danvk/sfhistory/blob/master/viewer/viewer.js#L122 (search for map_spacer). To make my custom control move the standard navigation controls DOWN instead of RIGHT, I had to add   zoomControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP } to my maps configuration.

Answer (score -7):

set

```
panControl : false,
```

in the ZoomControlsOptions which you set