# Control Positioning of Google's Drawing Library Toolset

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out an unofficial way (i.e., a hack) to move around Google's Drawing Library tools. There is no ID associated with it. Just a class name `gmnoprint`. But this class is pretty much on all of Google's controls and labels.

I found some related questions on Stack Overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924456/custom-position-non-custom-control-google-maps-v3-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934269/google-maps-api-v3-custom-controls-position)), but can't seem to figure out how to apply it to the Drawing Library. Whatever I've tried so far just breaks the functionality.

It seems unlikely that this can be done, but if there's a way... please let me know.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: move around to where ?

Comment: @Dr.Molle I am trying to position it outside of the map area if possible. Is there a way attach a `<div>` to it somehow through JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: See my update on http://stackoverflow.com/a/9773082/1106393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common detail which may be selected, all the controls contain a `img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/drawing.png"]`

Starting with this as selector you be able to move up to the closest ancestor `div.gmnoprint`, move it to where you wan't to.

Note: you must wait a little bit, the controls will be created asynchronously, the `tilesloaded`-event of the map seems to be a good moment.

Demo(using jquery, but this will also be possible with pure javascript) : http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/fnTGr/

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle. I never thought of doing it that way.