# How to position Google 'gmnoprint' copyright

Tags: openlayers

Since upgrading to OpenLayers 2.13, I'm trying to position my Google Map copyright in the lower left hand corner of the page, but it always wants to go to the lower right.

I tried this at load time (did not work):

```css
.gmnoprint{
left:'0px';
right:'';
}
```

I tried modifying the what I think is relevant lines in Openlayers.js (did not work):

```js
e = document.createElement("div");
e.id = this.map.id + "_GMap2Container";
e.style.position = "absolute";
e.style.width = "100%";
e.style.height = "100%";
d.appendChild(e);
try {
    a = new GMap2(e), b = e.lastChild, d.appendChild(b), b.style.zIndex =
        "1100", b.style.right = "",b.style.left = "0px", b.style.bottom = "", b.className = "olLayerGoogleCopyright", c = e.lastChild, d.appendChild(c), c.style.zIndex = "1100", c.style.right = "",c.style.left = "0px", c.style.bottom = "", c.className = "olLayerGooglePoweredBy gmnoprint"
} catch (f) {
    throw f;
}
```

I tried this after load using jQuery (works but only if you set a timeout which is a less than optimal choice since it causes a flicker as it repositions):

```js
$('.gmnoprint').css({'left':'0px','right':''})
```

What am I doing wrong with the first two attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first solution is, that the position of these elements is set directly inside the style attribute. So it overwrites the position, set by the class.

I guess the second one is not working, because some google javascript is messing around there besides the openlayers.js. But that's just a guess.

You could register yourself as an eventlistener to the layer and set you css there, but that will not solve your flicker problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934269/google-maps-api-v3-custom-controls-position) is a kind of solution, that worked for my needs.