# how to center google map's marker not in the middle of the map canvas

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(locationX,locationY);
```

if I do this way, google puts a marker in the center of map canvas. I want that it will be not center, bot for example top right corner. Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center the Google Map NOT at the center of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19206807/)

Comment: then you should not `setCenter`, you should use `panTo`

Comment: Yes it's possible but there's no specific built-in method. You have to do some maths to calculate an appropriate lat/lng offset then `.setCentre()` thereon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setCenter, try the following

> **`panTo(latLng:LatLng)`**
>
> Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is
> less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be
> smoothly animated.

Comment: the only difference would be  the possible animation, the result will be the same as if you use `setCenter()`