# How to make focus zone elsewhere than center in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any solution to have some like "focus zone" in Google Maps? So no matter what size of map is some point (no center) always will have the same position relative to parent block. It's can be confusing, so I made examples.

Start. Size of the map block is 400x175. We need to save yellow dot position relative to map block.
[image]

We increase window size and reload the page. Now we the map size is 1200x525. But position of the yellow dot changed.
[image]

The desired result is:
[image]

**UPD:** As you can see, in my example yellow dot always in the same geo location, it's actually the placemark of the building.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center the Google Map NOT at the center of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206807/how-to-center-the-google-map-not-at-the-center-of-the-screen)