# custom control position for street view google map

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am using street view on my site with pancontrols and zoomControls in it. For now google provides us some defined positions like RIGHT_CENTER etc. I want my custom position using css, I have taken help from this link [Google Maps API V3 custom controls position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934269/google-maps-api-v3-custom-controls-position) but it is not working may be because it is for Road map and I need for street view. The code which I have used for calling street view is

```
function initialize() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
  var panoOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 280.19,
      pitch: -22.444,
      zoom:0.2
    },
    addressControl: false,
    panControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    panControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
       style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
       position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
   },
   enableCloseButton: false
};

  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
  document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoOptions);
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Custom Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple?hl=es) examples and this [CUSTOM STREET VIEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/10/)

AFAIK you must link your panorama to the image of the streetview, thats nice if you want to make your own street view, if you want to get a google one, you must get the URL to force the view enter in *streetview*.

```
function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(pano, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
  // Note: robust custom panorama methods would require tiled pano data.
  // Here we're just using a single tile, set to the tile size and equal
  // to the pano "world" size.
  return 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQTaHe0F0J39SXbiRF43pz2wtyfD6kypCMrLxhWPkq9EACNgwO0iaMbJFM';
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change the arguments, or How can I give custom position in this? I want to change the position of zoom controls and Pan controls

Comment: set latLong with   `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.9,-2.08);` and use it as `center: myLatlng` in panoOptions....

Comment: Can you please change the position of zoom controls and pancontrols in fiddle, so that I can see how it has to be done. If possible please change it in between top center and top left

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/11/ updated fiddle, **NOTE: as you can read in the answer, you must get the image to show, setting new LatLon won't change the image but yes where maps thinks it is located...**. Please read with detail [Maps Api Llink](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple?hl=es)

Comment: And the link you have sent me is for custom street view but I want to make custom control positions in google map street view code

Comment: Can't we change the positions with normal google maps(without custom street view)

Answer (score 0):

You have everything that you need to do this in the answer that you linked to above.  You can pick from one of two choices:

1. The hack... This isn't recommended because if google maps decides to
   change their layout, your code will break.  To do this for
   streetview, inspect the streetview window to find which 'gmnoprint'
   you want to move.  As an example, putting this after the panorama
   load, moves the controls:

   `setTimeout( function() {
     $($('div.gmnoprint')[4]).css({left: '-300px', background: 'red'});
   }, 1000);`
2. The best way to do it, as suggested at [Google Maps API V3 custom controls position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934269/google-maps-api-v3-custom-controls-position#3094577) is to hide the streetview controls, create your own controls, and put them wherever you like.  This takes much more effort, but it will not break when the streetview layout changes.