# How can I have vertical drawing tool controls

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-drawing

I looked in the positioning docs and googled and don't see anything about it. This looks ridiculous tho even when their own controls are vertical. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934269/google-maps-api-v3-custom-controls-position

Comment: Yea, and that might work but it's extremely brittle: `$('div.gmnoprint').last()` assumes what I want will _always_ be last. `.gmnoprint`is used for all the controls + things like the terms of use link, etc. So if the DOM is ever changed and what I'm looking for is moved it'll all break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, and this isn't pretty, but the only way to get it aligned correctly and vertical was doing this hackage:

```
$('[title="Draw a rectangle"], [title="Stop drawing"]')
.last().css({marginBottom: '20px', marginLeft: '1px'})
.end().parent().css({
    float: 'none',
    marginLeft: '5px'
});
```

You'd need to add the `title` for each button you add to your controls too

**UPDATE**

The above worked fine for a bit but as I needed to add more buttons and have more control it became super hard. I ended up just building a "toolbar component" that didn't use *any* Google Maps code except to trigger the tool changes on click (just `drawingManagerInstance.setDrawingMode('whatever')`). This ended up taking me less time then figuring out how to alter theirs and it's so much easier to work with.