# iPhone X website safe area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, meta-tags

The iPhone X landscape default safe area and notch solution.

I added this Question to help others avoid a headache I head trying to fix my website on the new iPhone 10

Basically,  the problem is white bars

Comment: @Krunal safe area for website, not ios apps, thanks for your comment

Comment: @Krunal this is an example of how to use  `meta` content=`viewport-fit=cover` so kindly don't remove meta

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to use `viewport-fit=cover`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

This will use the full screen but what about the notch.

create a class

```
.iphoneX{
    padding: constant(safe-area-inset-top) constant(safe-area-inset-right) constant(safe-area-inset-bottom) constant(safe-area-inset-left);  
}
```

and add it to the website wrapper and done? Yes

No. Full-width images and Full-width divs with different colors will be cut

on my website, I use `<section>` to add background images or colors and add a div in the section for the content, so instead of `.iphoneX` on the website wrapper, i added `.iphoneX_rl` on the div

```
 .iphoneX_rl{
    padding: 0 constant(safe-area-inset-right) 0 constant(safe-area-inset-left);  
}
```

That takes care of the right and left what about the bottom

.iphoneX_footer{
padding: 0 0 constant(safe-area-inset-bottom) 0
  }

add this to -the last div ( container) in your footer

now my website looks good on iPhone X/10, looking at my website on the iPhone 8 content goes to the edge? no safe area time for js/jquery

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)/)){
  if((screen.availHeight == 812) && (screen.availWidth == 375)){

    if((window.innerHeight == "375") && (window.innerWidth == "812")){
      $('.someClass,.someClass,.someClass').addClass("iphoneX_rl");
      alert("ok iphone X - L");

    }else{
      $('.someClass,.someClass,.someClass').removeClass("iphoneX_rl");
      alert("ok iphone X - P");
    }

  }

}
```

`navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)/)` if any iPhone

`(screen.availHeight == 812) && (screen.availWidth == 375)` if iPhone 10

`((window.innerHeight == "375") && (window.innerWidth == "812"))` if landscape

does your website use google maps 
Add this to landscape `$('#map_section').addClass("gm_iphoneX");`

class

```
  .gm_iphoneX div.gmnoprint{ 
   margin-right: 40px !important; 

  }
```

if there is a better way to do it, or I missed something tell me 
THANKS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934269/google-maps-api-v3-custom-controls-position

Comment: https://www.designernews.co/stories/87581-another-solution-for-iphone-x-scrolling-by-embracing-the-notch

Comment: http://stephenradford.me/removing-the-white-bars-in-safari-on-iphone-x/

Answer (score 0):

Notes: In iOS UIWebView, the screen.availHeight is equal to 768.
In iOS WKWebView, the screen.availHeight is always 812.

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to javascript?

Comment: sorry thought this was an Apple API you were referring to