# Detect Iphone X using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone-x

I have a native app in iOS that load a hybrid application using a web view. The hybrid app is build in jquery and kendo.js.

I need to detect in the hybrid app if the device is the iPhone X. I don´t know if it is possible to detect the device on the native side and send a parameter to the web application side.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way for me is to append something like `?device=iphonex` to the url your are loading in the webview. It's dirty I guess

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x) to detect the iPhone X device and then you can send the bool value with a GET request (for example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if the device is iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192280/detect-if-the-device-is-iphone-x)

Comment: While you CAN detect it natively, you can also detect it in HTML by [checking the user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354349/iphone-x-website-safe-area) and maybe the resolition. You can also just adapt your design [using the new iPhone X CSS constants](https://www.bram.us/2017/09/14/introducing-user-agent-variables-rendering-sites-fullscreen-in-safari-on-iphone-x/).