# How can I prevent content from being visible above the toolbar for notched phones like iPhone X?

Tags: ios, css, scroll, toolbar, angular-material2

I have an app that uses Angular Material Design 2 (wrapped in Cordova) and has a toolbar and sidenav.  On notched phones that run iOS (like the iPhone X), when the user scrolls the content on the page is visible above the toolbar where the notch area is.  This doesn't happen on my LG G7, which has a notch and is running Android, though that may just be my settings because I think I remember "hiding" the notch.

I've sort of proven that this isn't phone specific by taking the example StackBlitz that Material Design provides for responsive layout and deliberately adding some margin to it to create an artificial space.  See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdh21g . When you scroll, you can see where the content is still visible above the toolbar.  I am wondering what CSS I need to add to force the content's top limit to remain below the toolbar?  I tried various settings for the meta tag in my HTML for viewport-fit, but nothing seems to change it.  Here is what it is right now:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

So essentially, I need to either force the top of the page to be below the notch, or force the content to stay below the toolbar.

EDIT:  I just realized that the HTML portion might be relevant because it uses "fixedTopGap" - a portion of it is below:

```
  <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container"
                         [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
                 [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches" fixedTopGap="56">
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="." *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <p *ngFor="let content of fillerContent">{{content}}</p>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354349/iphone-x-website-safe-area